# What would happen if 2 mod candidates withdrew?

Tags: support, moderator-election

The election rules say

> After 7 days, the top 30 nominees, ordered by reputation, advance to
>   the primary phase. However, if there are 10 or fewer candidates, we
>   skip directly to the election phase.
>
> The primary is not binding; nominees may withdraw at their discretion
>   at any point during the primary phase.
>
> After 4 days, the top 10 candidates based on primary vote score
>   proceed onward to the election phase.

What happens if when the nomination phase ends there are n > 10 candidates, but during the primary phase m >= n-10 candidates withdraw?

For the current election we have 12 candidates, if 2 withdrew there would be 10.

Would we need to wait until the 4 days ended, or would the primary phase end prematurely?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [this declined feature request to skip the primary phase if enough candidates withdraw](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2622/skip-the-primary-phase-if-enough-candidates-withdraw), the phase continues as planned.

> We won't be skipping the primary phase - it still serves a function if any other people wish to withdraw.